# IOS insert into db not working

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, sql-insert

Please find below what i have been trying.

```
-(BOOL)addItemsToTable:(NSString *)useTable WithColumnValues:(NSDictionary *) ValueObject{

    BOOL hasbeenAdded=NO;
    NSString *myColumns = @"";
    NSString *myValues = @"";
    for(int r=0; r<[self.columns count];r++){
        NSString *this_keyname = [self.columns objectAtIndex:r];
        myColumns = [myColumns stringByAppendingString:this_keyname];
        NSString *thisValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", @"a"];
        myValues = [myValues stringByAppendingString:thisValue];
        if(r<(([[ValueObject allKeys]count])-1)){
            myColumns = [myColumns stringByAppendingString:@","];
            myValues = [myValues stringByAppendingString:@","];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@-%@", myColumns, myValues);
    NSString *myInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (%@) VALUES (%@)",useTable, myColumns, myValues];
    char *err;
    if((sqlite3_exec(database, [myInsert UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err))!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSLog(@"Not added");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Added");
        hasbeenAdded = YES;
    }
    return hasbeenAdded;

}
```

Mycolumns and myvalues are printing properly as the fields in the database, but it always enters the if condition and prints not added. Please help where i am going wrong!!

Comment: Do you have write permission to the directory that the database file is located in?

Comment: If it prints "Not added" it doesn't enter the else condition ;)

Comment: If you actually read the SQLite documentation you'll see that there is a sqlite3_errmsg method (or something like that) that will return a very valuable message after an error.  Also, capture the return code from sqlite3_exec since it contains valuable information.  Dealing with SQLite requires being able to read documentation.

Comment: (Basically, you have to make some effort to debug this, then give us all the pertinent error info, vs simply telling us it doesn't work.)

Comment: Log your `myInsert` string, check in database is there is all field are ok or not.

Comment: Your code forgets to free `err`. (And should log it so that you know what's going on.)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you can check what exact error occurred using error

```
    if ( sqlite3_exec(DB, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK0
{

 }
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error : %s", error);
 }
```

How ever try your insert statement with single quotes while like \'%@\'.

```
 NSString *myInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (%@) VALUES (\'%@\')",useTable, myColumns, myValues];
```